# How to modify Order attribute of a post on DOM

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom

Just want to ask if it's possible to modify/update a wordpress post's order attribute on dom through Javascript?

We have a radio website and one of the requirements is a location specific channel.

Example, we have 5 Locations and 5 Radio Channels.
Location 1 should load Radio Channel #1, Location 2 should load Radio Channel #2, etc.

Right now I was able to remove other radio channels on the generated ul list through JavaScript, but the theme is loading the radio channel #1 by default even though the selected location is #2.

I'm thinking maybe it is due to the order value assigned on the radio channels.

Hope anyone could help me this one. Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you don't want to fix the underlying problem of why the right post's are not showing up in the first place?

Comment: well the correct radio channel is displayed on the sidebar while the Now Playing section is displaying the radio channel with the order attribute of 0. For example, I selected Location #2, on the sidebar it displays Radio Channel #2 but on the Now Playing section it displays Radio Channel #1